# Unexpected results in prolog

Tags: prolog

Why do I get so many true results instead of just one? Here are how I define my rules:

```
parent(X,Y):- or(father(X,Y), mother(X,Y)).   
sister(X,Y):- female(X), parent(P, X), parent(P,Y).      
aunt(X,Y):- female(X), sister(X,P), parent(P,Y).


?- aunt(molly, johnny).
true ;
true ;
true ;
true ;
true ;
true ;
true ;
true ;
true ;
true.
```

Comment: No way we can tell without seeing the definitions of the predicates involved. My guess is that `sister` and/or `parent` succeed multiple times for the given input.

Comment: @Steven I added the rules for parent() and sister()

Comment: You can use a cut as you find first solution, it will not backtrack anymore .

Comment: You should put a cut in your code not in query but try to write a query like and see it will return one time return `aunt(molly, johnny),!.`

Comment: @LuaiGhunim a cut is not really the correct way to solve this. Cut is often used as a band-aid that many Prolog beginners used to fix poorly defined rules.

Comment: You haven't sufficiently constrained your definition for `sister/2`. What prevents `X` and `Y` from being the same person in this rule? Nothing currently. So you want to add another constraint: `sister(X, Y) :- female(X), dif(X, Y), parent(P, X), parent(P, Y).`

Comment: Where did you come up with the `or(father(X,Y), mother(X,Y)). ` syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Steven mentioned in his comment, the result depends on the predicates you have, especially the atom ones. for example the following code will result in a two "true" result because `parent(X,Y):- father(X,Y);mother(X,Y).`
would match both the father and mother predicates for molly & alex.

```
father(dan,molly).
father(dan,alex).
father(alex,johnny).

mother(jess,molly).
mother(jess,alex).

female(molly).

parent(X,Y):- father(X,Y) ; mother(X,Y).

sister(X,Y):- female(X), parent(P, X), parent(P,Y), X \= Y.

aunt(X,Y):- sister(X,P), parent(P,Y).

?- aunt(molly, johnny).
true ;
true .
```

If you need to get a single matching (e.g. a single `true` result), you could use the cut `!` predicate at the end of aunt predicate, such as `aunt(X,Y):- female(X), sister(X,P), parent(P,Y),!.`

In this case the code will be as follows:

```
father(dan,molly).
father(dan,alex).
father(alex,johnny).

mother(jess,molly).
mother(jess,alex).

female(molly).

parent(X,Y):- father(X,Y) ; mother(X,Y).

sister(X,Y):- female(X), parent(P, X), parent(P,Y), X \= Y.

aunt(X,Y):- sister(X,P), parent(P,Y),!.

?- aunt(molly, johnny).
true .
```

Comment: @H H is there a fix to this?

Comment: You need to add conditions somewhere to avoid it, or you can use `setof/3` or something similar. Do not just sprinkle cuts over your code as other people suggest from time to time.

Comment: Wrap `setof(t, Goal_0, _)` around the goal!

Comment: `sister(molly, molly)` succeeds. `molly` is not her own sister. And `sister/2` already checks that the first argument is female, so the `female(X)` call in `aunt(X,Y)` is redundant.  `aunt(molly, johnny)` succeeds twice because `sister/2` can succeed twice since sisters share two parents.

Comment: @Scrappy Montana, If you want a simple and quick solution you could use the cut predicate `!`, as advised by the guys here. However, it might not be the best practice. I have updated the answer to show you how you can use the cut predicate, and I also removed the redundant `female(X)`  call and fixed the `sister(molly, molly)` as recommended by @lurker